# The common area of the circle with the center of an earthquake and the city where the earthquake occurred

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have a number of earthquakes - earthquakes above 5 Richter - in the last hundred years in one country. I also have the shapefile of the country's cities. How do I calculate what percent of each city overlaps with a 20km buffer around the earthquake points?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Have you tried the Buffer tool to create circle polygons from point features?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the location of the earthquates? If yes, are they given as 2D or 3D points? And in which coordinates reference frame? These two last questions also goes for your cities shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the cities is a polygon dataset. Use file geodatabase feature classes for this so that shape areas get recalculated automatically.

1. Add a field to the cities called CityArea and use field calculator to set it equal to ShapeArea. You need to do this to preserve the value through the steps that follow.
2. Use the buffer tool to create your buffer circles. If you do not want to double-count the area of a city that falls into two overlapping buffers, choose the option of merging the buffer polygons.
3. Use the intersect tool to combine the buffer circles and the cities.
4. Resulting polygons will be the buffer polys where they overlap with the cities, with the attributes of both. Add a field for PctOverlap, and use field calculator to make it equal to ShapeArea / CityArea * 100.
5. You will have one record for each quake in each city. If you want, you can create a summary table so you have one record for each city and a field for sum_PctOverlap.